Riemannian metric for which arbitary path becomes a geodesic
I was thinking about the following problem today. Suppose we have a smooth path $\gamma : [a,b] \to M$, where $M$ is a smooth manifold. Is it always possible to construct a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that $\gamma$ becomes a geodesic? I would like to see whether or not there is a simple example about this in the case for example when $M = \Bbb R^2$ and $\gamma(t) = (t, f(t))$ is a smooth path.

I'll make an attempt at the example you've asked about. Let's assume that $f$ is smooth.
Define
$$
E(x, y) = (x, y - f(x)).
$$
Then $E$ sends the curve $\gamma$ to the curve $\nu(t) = (t, 0)$, which is certainly a geodesic in the standard metric (let's call it $s$) on $\mathbb R^2$, right? Furthermore, $E$ is a diffeomorphism.
Suppose we let $g = E^{*}s$ be the pullback of $s$ by the map $E$. Because $E$ is a diffeomorphism, $g$ defines a metric on the plane. Furthermore, the map $E$ becomes an isometry between (1) the plane with metric $g$ and (2) the plane with metric $s$. So under the metric $g$, your curve $\gamma$ will be a geodesic.
You can probably generalize, but the case where $\gamma$ is a general curve (possibly with self-intersections) might be difficult; the case where it's a smoothly embedded curve should be not too difficult, although maybe you need something about ambient isotopy to "straighten it out" -- I'm not thinking clearly enough to say anything confidently about that.
